# SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. jquery.min.js, line 2 character 91826

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Another Internet Explorer Javascript error. I can't debug  as well since Internet Explorer's debugging tool is even slower than Eclipse which is quite an achievement.... Can anybody see what's causing the SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error.  jquery.min.js, line 2 character 91826 error?

Comment: Errors in jquery.js are usually caused by incorrect usage of a jQuery function. Can you isolate *when* it happens? What does your page do when it turns up?

Comment: @Pekka It however only shows in Internet Explorer... When the page is loaded various ajax calls are being made. Like `$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "\/slider.php", }).done(function( html ) {
  $("#jui").html(html);
  if ($("#vpo").html().length == 0)
  activateSlider();
 });`

Comment: Strange... the only thing in your code that strikes me as odd is the backslash in the ajax URL, what's it doing there? Other than that, are you 100% sure `$("#jui")` and `$("#vpo")`  exist?

Comment: Yes they do. I have to put the backslash because otherwise '/slider.php' would give an error i think....

Comment: A backslash to escape a slash? I don't think you need that. Try removing it just in case... Other than that, the only idea that comes to me is to use `alert()`s instead of the debugger, maybe you can isolate the problem more exactly that way (I've never really figured out to use the MS debugger, either.)

Comment: Try to convert a string with a "/" at http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/. They escape it there also. I've now removed it though and Internet Explorer isn't giving errors anymore :s. So i guess that was what the problem was....

Comment: That makes sense - I think IE treats the backslash differently for historical reasons (it being the path separator on Windows systems). I'll add it as an answer, I think this is worth keeping around

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You say you are using this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
  { $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "\/slider.php", }).done(
       function( html ) { 
        $("#jui").html(html); 
        if ($("#vpo").html().length == 0) activateSlider();
  });
```

remove the backslash from the URL. I'm not *completely* sure why this causes an error, but IE traditionally handles backslashes in URLs differently than other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question now but I figured I'd throw in another solution.  YMMV but I had an old add-on that was causing the same problem.  After uninstalling, the problem was resolved.